Updating Gravity Forms Product price in hook
I'm trying to update the price of a product field on a multi page form through a gform_pre_render hook, and it does not seem to work. In the code below, I am able to set the content of an input box (Field 41) but cannot change the price value of the product field (Field 42). Is there a way to update the price?
add_filter( 'gform_pre_render_2', function($form) {
    $current_page = \GFFormDisplay::get_current_page( $form['id'] );
    if ( $current_page == 3 ) {
        foreach( $form['fields'] as &$field ) {
            //get html field
            if ( $field->id == 41 ) {
                //set the field content to the html
                $field->defaultValue = 'Content from pre-render';
                
            }
            if ( $field->id == 42 ) {
                $field->basePrice = 500;
                $field->defaultValue = "$500 CAD";
            }
        }
    }
    return $form;

I've tried a number of combinations for my pricing field, but it does not seem to change the value.

You can try this modify version of your code and see if it works.
<?php
 add_filter( 'gform_pre_render_2', function($form) {
    $current_page = \GFFormDisplay::get_current_page( $form['id'] );
    if ( $current_page == 3 ) {
        foreach( $form['fields'] as &$field ) {
            if ( $field->id == 41 ) {
                $field->defaultValue = 'Content from pre-render';
            }
            if ( $field->id == 42 && $field->type == 'product' ) {
               
                $field->price = 500;
                
                if ( is_array( $field->inputs ) ) {
                    foreach ( $field->inputs as &$input ) {
                        if ( $input['id'] == '42.2' ) { 
                            $input['defaultValue'] = 500;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $form;
});

?>

Use the gform_pre_render hook to adjust the pricing of a product field in a Gravity Form on a specified page. The original effort was unsuccessful since the pricing did not adjust as expected.
